# Break text into letters (regular Unicode graphemes+language specific digraphs)

Tags: python, parsing, unicode

In English, "Sh" is two letters. In other languages it's considered a single letter. I'm trying to calculate the length of a string in [a Unicode aware way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57617653/how-do-i-count-letters-in-a-string), with this in mind. I'm imagining a function like

```
def count_letters(my_string, lang="en")
```

But here's how I would do that for just one language, using a library that has had no new versions since 2015, [`uniseg`](https://bitbucket.org/emptypage/uniseg-python/src/default/):

```
from uniseg.graphemecluster import grapheme_clusters


def albanian_digraphs(s, breakables):
    digraphs = ["Dh", "Gj", "Ll", "Nj", "Rr", "Sh", "Th", "Xh", "Zh"]
    digraphs += [d.lower() for d in digraphs]
    for i, breakable in enumerate(breakables):
        for first, second in digraphs:
            if s.endswith(first, 0, i) and s.startswith(second, i):
                yield 0
                break
        else:
            yield breakable


# from https://sq.wiktionary.org/wiki/Speciale:PrefixIndex?prefix=dh
for text in ('dhallanik', 'dhelpëror', 'dhembshurisht', 'dhevështrues', 'dhimbshëm', 'dhjamosje', 'dhjetëballësh', 'dhjetëminutësh', 'dhogaç', 'dhogiç', 'dhomë-muze', 'dhuratë', 'dhëmbinxhi', 'dhëmbçoj', 'dhëmbëkatarosh'):
    print(list(grapheme_clusters(text, albanian_digraphs)))

#['dh', 'a', 'll', 'a', 'n', 'i', 'k']
#['dh', 'e', 'l', 'p', 'ë', 'r', 'o', 'r']
#['dh', 'e', 'm', 'b', 'sh', 'u', 'r', 'i', 'sh', 't']
#['dh', 'e', 'v', 'ë', 'sh', 't', 'r', 'u', 'e', 's']
#['dh', 'i', 'm', 'b', 'sh', 'ë', 'm']
#['dh', 'j', 'a', 'm', 'o', 's', 'j', 'e']
#['dh', 'j', 'e', 't', 'ë', 'b', 'a', 'll', 'ë', 'sh']
#['dh', 'j', 'e', 't', 'ë', 'm', 'i', 'n', 'u', 't', 'ë', 'sh']
#['dh', 'o', 'g', 'a', 'ç']
#['dh', 'o', 'g', 'i', 'ç']
#['dh', 'o', 'm', 'ë', '-', 'm', 'u', 'z', 'e']
#['dh', 'u', 'r', 'a', 't', 'ë']
#['dh', 'ë', 'm', 'b', 'i', 'n', 'xh', 'i']
#['dh', 'ë', 'm', 'b', 'ç', 'o', 'j']
#['dh', 'ë', 'm', 'b', 'ë', 'k', 'a', 't', 'a', 'r', 'o', 'sh']
```

Comment: @Graipher According to [the](https://bitbucket.org/emptypage/uniseg-python/src/default/uniseg/graphemecluster.py) [code](https://bitbucket.org/emptypage/uniseg-python/src/default/uniseg/breaking.py), `s` is the original string and `breakables` is a list of similar length containing zeroes or ones. Ones mean break before the corresponding letter, zeroes mean keep the corresponding letter in the same grapheme than the previous one. The function's purpose is to modify `breakables` before breaks are applied to `s`.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger Ah, I did not see that the function was used by another function...thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For starter, you do not need to create you `digraphs` list each time the function is called: they won't change, so better create them once as a global constant. You also forgot to add capitalized versions in the list so that `'HELLO'` is split into `['H', 'E', 'LL', 'O']` instead of the current `['H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O']`.

Second, your linear research in the `digraphs` list can be time consuming when all you want to know is if characters at position `i-1` (if any) and `i` forms a digraph present in your list. I’d rather write it as `yield 0 if s[i-1:i+1] in digraphs else breakable`. Of course, for this to work efficiently, you will need `digraphs` to be a `set` instead of a `list` where lookups are \$\mathcal{O}(1)\$ instead of \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$.

Lastly, I would only consider lowercase variants and turn the selected two characters lowercase before checking:

```
from uniseg.graphemecluster import grapheme_clusters


DIGRAPHS = {"dh", "gj", "ll", "nj", "rr", "sh", "th", "xh", "zh"}


def albanian_digraphs(s, breakables):
    for i, breakable in enumerate(breakables):
        yield 0 if s[i-1:i+1].lower() in DIGRAPHS else breakable


if __name__ == '__main__':    
    # from https://sq.wiktionary.org/wiki/Speciale:PrefixIndex?prefix=dh
    for text in ('dhallanik', 'dhelpëror', 'dhembshurisht', 'dhevështrues', 'dhimbshëm', 'dhjamosje', 'dhjetëballësh', 'dhjetëminutësh', 'dhogaç', 'dhogiç', 'dhomë-muze', 'dhuratë', 'dhëmbinxhi', 'dhëmbçoj', 'dhëmbëkatarosh'):
        print(list(grapheme_clusters(text, albanian_digraphs)))
```

Also note the use of [`if __name__ == '__main__'`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/419163/5069029) to separate the actual code from the tests.

Comment: [According to Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albanian_alphabet) the uppercase version of the Albanian letter "sh" is "Sh", not "SH". So not clustering "SH" was deliberate. But I guess it doesn't matter, it's worth the simplification of the code.

Comment: @Boris Well, you can always drop the `.lower()` call and restore your original collection of digraphs if you think it fits your intended usage better.